# Symfony 2.6 : How to get the current provider used to log in?

Tags: php, symfony, entity, provider

I' am facing an issue in my SF2.6 project. I have two sort of user(Client, Employee) so I'am using multiple entity provider

```
providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [employee, client]
    employee:
        entity: { class: SpeedDev\MyprojectsBundle\Entity\Employee, property: emailEmp }
    client:
        entity: { class: SpeedDev\MyprojectsBundle\Entity\Client, property: contactemailClient }
```

that work I can log into my application as a client or an Employee and SF goes check in the right table for the credentials.

My issue is that I need to retrieve which entity between employee or client  sf has used as a provider so I know which entity's function to use between $this->getUser()->getIdEmp() or $this->getUser()->getIdClient()

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check if your `$this->getUser()` is `instanceof` your desired entity:

```
if ($this->getUser() instanceof SpeedDev\MyprojectsBundle\Entity\Employee) {
    // this is employee
}
```

Comment: instead of SpeedDev\MyprojectsBundle\Entity\Employee I had to use juste Employee which is my entity name